# Can you cast the "Magic Weapon" spell on a magical weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, weapons

The spell simply says "you touch a non-magical weapon" and it becomes magical for up to an hour (concentration required) with a +1 bonus. If you cast it with a 4th level slot, you get a +2, and with a 6th level slot, a +3.

Since there are +1/+2/+3 buffs also associated with this spell, I was wondering if you could buff an already-magical weapon temporarily with this spell.  Not stacking, but just changing a +1 weapon to a +2 for a minute, for example.

I suspect this almost never comes up, but I just was curious about the somewhat-ambiguous wording since there's no explicit restrictive wording that it ONLY works on non-magical weapons.

Comment: ♦ Reminder: comments are for clarifying content, [not posting small or incomplete answers](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6534). Please only use answer posts to submit answers on the site. Prior comments containing answers have been removed.

Comment: RE: "[T]here's no explicit restrictive wording that it ONLY works on non-magical weapons." As a writer who values precision and an avid reader of instructions and rules, I ask, in all seriousness, how can this spell's targeting be rephrased so as to eliminate any confusion?

Answer (score 22):

### The weapon has to be nonmagical

> You touch a **nonmagical weapon**. Until the spell ends, **that weapon** becomes a magic weapon with a +1 bonus to attack rolls and damage rolls.

The spell explicitly says the weapon touched has to be nonmagical, and only grants effects to the touched weapon in particular. It can't be stacked on existing magical enchantments.

Comment: This spell has been revised and the nonmagical word removed from the text. So this answer is no longer valid. https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=182

Answer (score 7):

The spell simply doesn't work if you touch a magical weapon. The spell requires you to touch a non-magical weapon in order to properly cast it, and touching a magical weapon doesn't count as that, so it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

No the weapon needs to be non magical for the spell to affect it, therefore it cannot be magical.